# Super simple yet impossible menu

Tags: html, menu, fadein, fadeout

How do I do this?
A menu with 3 links (A B C).
"A.html" is shown at start.
When link "B" is clicked, "A" is faded out and "B" fades in.

Every time a link is clicked. Content is changed by fadeout and fadein.
If possible I would like the browsers back buttom to work.

```
<div menu>
 <link> A </link>
 <link> B </link>
 <link> C </link>
</div menu>

<div content>
 A
</div content>
```

Comment: it is not impossible . Try jQuery UI.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor such a simple operation wouldn't need jQuery UI per se ;)

Answer (score 1):

you will need javascript or jquery for that

see your impossible possible below:

place your markup like this

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="active">
         <a href="#"  > A </a>
         <div class="A hidden">
            <h1> Hello I am A </h1>
            <img src="y.jpg">         
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#" > B </a>
         <div class="B hidden">
            <h1> Hello I am B </h1>
            <img src="y.jpg"> 
        </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

and place a simple jQuery code like this:

```
//find the changeContent function to the click of anchors 
$('a').on('click',function(){
    changeContent(this);
});

//load the first content by default
changeContent($('li.active').find('a:first')); 

function changeContent(target){
     $('li').removeClass('active');
     $(target).parent().addClass('active');
     $('.content').html($(target).siblings('div').html());
 }
```

TADA!! its done.

see this in [live](http://jsfiddle.net/FJcGC/1/)

Comment: Please review the OP's question. He asked for a switched on fadeIns and fadeOuts on the buttons. You don't, or forgot to, show that ;)

Comment: I tested it. But the html that is loaded replace the index.html. [CHECK IT OUT](http://www.superfresh.se/fade/index.html) I want something [like this](http://superfresh.se/test02/).

Comment: exactly. why have you kept three different pages a.html, b.html,c.html? just copy the content(inside body) of each page and place it inside the respective divs on index.html

Comment: How Manish? Lets say if I click on buttom named "A". I want something like this displayed:
    <div>
    <img src="y.jpg">
    <h1> Hello </h1>
    </div>

Where do I put that code?

Comment: see, you don't need a separate page for that, you can keep whatever you want to be displayed(upon click) on the page in the beginning itself, but hidden, and when you click it just appears. see my answer now. its super simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fAvcq/9/

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">A</a>
    <a href="#" class="active">B</a>
    <a href="#">C</a>
</div>
<div id="content">A</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a[class=active]').fadeOut('slow');

    $('#menu a').click(function(){
        $('#menu a[class=active]').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#menu a[class=active]').removeClass();

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#menu a[class=active]').fadeOut('slow');

        $('#content').html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: I want something [LIKE THIS](http://superfresh.se/test02/). If it is possible. Without php wich this site uses.